# Mozc does not work for Qt applications

Tags: 11.04, qt, input-method, japanese, mozc

I installed Ubuntu Natty 2011.04 from scratch, and then [mozc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ibus-mozc) (Google's IME, which I prefer to other options) which provides Japanese input.

It works in all applications EXCEPT Qt-based applications like Opera, Anki, ksnapshot, ...

How can I fix it, so that I can type Japanese in Qt/KDE applications as well?

Comment: Opera is not a Qt application anymore, and might not work with just about any input method (maybe ibus, but no guarantee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing ibus-qt4, then logging out and back in fixed it for me.
I also found this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111087

Answer (score 1):

Mozc can be used by QT applications, if you will install  **ibus-qt4** :

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-qt4
```

and an environment variable will be changed by using this comannd :

```
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

If you want to set up this to an global environment variable, describes as follows to **~/.xprofile**.

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XIM_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/ibus-daemon
```