# Japanese input stopped working for QT applications in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, qt, input-method, japanese, mozc

I'm using Anki to create flash cards for Japanese words. It worked last time I've checked, but now it doesn't even if I set input mode to hiragana. I've followed instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51716/mozc-does-not-work-for-qt-applications), but to no avail, even after I've rebooted my system.

`QT_IM_MODULE` is set to ibus.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is the `libqt5gui5` package installed?

Comment: It's already installed. (version 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.3). Interestingly, in CopyQ (clipboard manager I use) which also uses QT japanese input works.

Comment: If you don't mind to switch IME engine, there are many other choices, e.g. uim-mozc and fcitx-mozc. You can install all of these and switch it when you need it. Report the error to the Ubuntu/Linux community someone will fix it.

Comment: This was most most likely due to [bug #1844853](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1844853), so I voted for closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try/choose to install as many as possible japanese IMEs for [ibus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus):

- [Mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`, and/or;
- [Anthy](https://osdn.net/projects/anthy/): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`, and/or;
- [SKK](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-skk): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`, and/or;
- [KKC](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-kkc): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`.

Switch between them.
Maybe one can be used to input your japanese content.

Comment: No, no, the question is most likely due to [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1844853) which has been fixed.

Comment: I thought it was a generic problem with ibus, so I came with these alternative input solutions. Thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson for point out that was a bug and was resolved.